# How can I display data from multiple tables using a code-first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a code-first approach to display data from multiple tables using SQL Server. For my [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) semester project, I'm building a social networking website. In my index view I want to display data from two tables, that is, from Posts and Comments.

I'm trying a lot but nothing below is in my Index action.

First, I was using this but later I think it performs only a simple join between tables.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var myobj = DB.Comments.Include("Post").ToList();
    return View(myobj);
}
```

If I use the SQL query below instead of above inside my Index action and pass them to the view, it generates an exception. How do I avoid that?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var myobj = from u in DB.Posts
                     join b in DB.Comments
                     on u.UserID equals b.UserID
                     into obj
                     from ua in obj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { userComments = (ua == null) ? "" : ua.UserComments, UserPosts = u.UserPosts };

     return View(myobj);
 }
```

where inside Index.cshtml I'm using a strongly typed View:

```
@model IEnumerable<myApp.Models.DB.Comment>
```

and then display all posts and comments using a `foreach` loop.

But it displays only those posts which postID is present in the Comments table (foreign key from post is in the comment table).

How would I display all posts along with their comments (if any)?

---

I'm using an .edmx file for the backend while for retrieving/adding data from the database I'm using a code-first approach.

Here's a code example:

```
private SocialNetworkingEntities net = new SocialNetworkingEntities();

    public void Add(RegisterView user)
    {
        DB.UserInfo User = new DB.UserInfo();
        User.Name = user.UserName;
        User.Password = user.UserPassword;
        User.Email = user.UserEmail;
        User.Birthday = user.UserDOB;
        User.Sex = user.UserSex;
        net.UserInfoes.Add(User);
        net.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the posts with optional comments, then `Post` and not `Comment` is your main model type. Also, you don't have to manually join tables like you do in your second approach - that is done by EF automatically.

So first use the pattern of your first approch and change it to return the posts. The comments are accessible by your navigation property (Posts):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var allPosts = DB.Posts.Include("Comments").ToList();
    return View(allPosts);
}
```

Second, change the modeltype in your view to `Post`:

```
@model IEnumerable<myApp.Models.DB.Post>
```

Now you should be able to enumerate all Posts and optional the Comments:

```
@foreach (Post post in Model) {
    // display post
    foreach (Comment comment in post.Comments) {
        // display comment
    }
}
```

Comment: but problem is that in my comment table foriegn key is present from post table i.e postID i have already use this ( var allPosts = DB.Posts.Include("Comments").ToList(); )
but it generates exception becoz post table has no association with comment table in my index view if i use (@model IEnumerable<myApp.Models.DB.Post>
) than i cant access the comments simple i want to show data just like in facebook sequence ]

Comment: So why don't you just add that association to your model? How can you write `Include("Comments")` then?

Comment: so kindly tell me how can i associate post to comment which field/column i should relate?? and how is possible.

Comment: That depends mainly on your dataaccess technology you use. You just wrote *code first*. I guess its Entity Framework? But which version? Do you really use code first or do you have an edmx file? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your second approach is that your View is expecting a ViewModel of type Comment. But if you look at the query you return an anonymous type instead of a comment.

In your first query you start with Comments and load all the Posts for the comments. This way you wouldn't get posts that don't have any comments.

I think the easiest way is to define an association from Posts to Comments and change your query to:

```
var myobj = DB.Posts.Include("Comments").ToList();
```

If you then modify your View to accept a Model of type `Post` everything should work.